# recognize separate normal distributions in one data set

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, probability

A model I have constructed produces output which takes the shape of three normal distributions.

```
import numpy as np
d1 = [np.random.normal(2,.1) for _ in range(100)]
d2 = [np.random.normal(2.5,.1) for _ in range(100)]
d3 = [np.random.normal(3,.1) for _ in range(100)]
sudo_model_output = d1 + d2 + d3
np.random.shuffle(sudo_model_output)
```

[image]

What is a pythonic way to find the normal distribution mean and standard deviation associated with each normal distribution? I cannot hardcode an estimate of where the distributions start and end (~ 2.25 and 2.75 here) because the value will change with each iteration of my simulation.

Comment: You can try to fit the sum of three normaldistributions, each with it's own center and width, that would make 6 variables to fit. If the widths are expected to be similar you could get away with 4 variables (center1,ctr2,ctr3, width).

Comment: To do this I would need to somehow separate the data right?

Comment: No, you can't know whether a given value belongs to a given distribution if they are very close together. You just fit the sum, see attempted answer below.

Comment: The stats jargon for what you are calling "separate distributions in one data set" is "a mixture model."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I adapted the fit from : [Fitting a histogram with python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hujA.png)

```
from scipy.optimize import leastsq
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as p
%matplotlib inline

d1 = [np.random.normal(2,.1) for _ in range(1000)]
d2 = [np.random.normal(2.5,.1) for _ in range(1000)]
d3 = [np.random.normal(3,.1) for _ in range(1000)]
sum1 = d1 + d2 + d3
bins=np.arange(0,4,0.01)
a=np.histogram(sum1,bins=bins)

fitfunc  = lambda p, x: p[0]*exp(-0.5*((x-p[1])/p[2])**2) +\
        p[3]*exp(-0.5*((x-p[4])/p[5])**2) +\
        p[6]*exp(-0.5*((x-p[7])/p[8])**2)

errfunc  = lambda p, x, y: (y - fitfunc(p, x))

xdata,ydata=bins[:-1],a[0]
p.plot(xdata,ydata) 

init  = [40, 2.1, 0.1,40, 2.4, 0.1,40, 3.1, 0.1 ]

out   = leastsq(errfunc, init, args=(xdata, ydata))
c = out[0]
print c
```

[image]

Now that fit looks pretty good, but I came very close with the inital guesses (see init) for the amplitude, center and width of these 9 variables. If you knew that they were all the same height or width and could therefore lower the number of variables, it would help the fit.